creating a CIRAWFilter directly from bayer pixel data
I've written a small app that plays back 12 bit dng sequences by passing 12 bit dngs to a metal view via CIRAWFilter via the CIRAWFilter(imageUR: url). Everything's working as expected!
Now, instead of passing DNG files, I'd like to pass a data objectec directly with the CIRAWFilter(imageData: Data, identifierHint: String) method to translate a Data object which contains 12 bit bayer pixel data into a CIImage, but I'm having trouble understanding how to use the identifierHint or how to create a CIRAWFilter with manually determined properties?
I'm having trouble finding good documentation for this method so any direction to more complete documentation or code examples would be a life saver!
